# ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape (Machine Learning)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, numpy-ndarray

I am having a problem with one of my Machine Learning homework assignments. We are asked to use machine learning in order to estimate the age of an individual given an image. We are given a dataset of 28360 train images and 7090 test images.

The issue I'm having is in snippet #3 of my code that can be found [**HERE :)**](https://pastebin.com/HVL6SqqJ)
In particular, I'm getting `ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape`. Like I mentioned above, my train data set has a size of 28360. After running the program, from `temp.append(img)` i can the place `print(len(temp))` which gives me again, 28360. Maybe I don't have a comprehensive understanding of what exactly `np.stack(temp)` is doing or how it works, but the sizes of my initial and final array seem to be the same so why the issue.?

Asked around and am being told that the issue isn't necessarily with the length of my `temp` list, but rather that I may be running into an image which isn't of the same size as the others. That one or more of the contained resized images (which are arrays) have a different shape, maybe because the resize failed or the image is missing or something. If this is the case, how would finding which are different and why in a dataset of 28360 images so I could fix them or drop them.? Is this really the issue, or may it be something else.?

Anyone, please help. What am I doing wrong? Any comments/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance. Cheers and good day.! :D

Comment: When you get an error, you should tell us where it occurs.  That may require showing some or all of the traceback.  But the error is the kind of thing that `np.stack` raises when the arrays it's trying to join differ in shape.  That means you need to look at  the list of arrays and find the one(s) that differ in shape.  Do you know how to see the `shape` of an array?

Comment: So the error occurs in line 45 of my source code. I also included all the trackback in above, but [**HERE**](https://pastebin.com/HVL6SqqJ) it is again. To find the shape of an array, I'm using something similarily to `print('test x shape:', test_x.shape) ` correct.? A bit confused, however. What do you mean by "look at the list of arrays and find the one(s) that differ in shape".? Thanks again for the swift reply.

Comment: `[x.shape for x in temp]` should list the shapes of all elements of the `temp` list.  (We tend to favor code and tracebacks that are copy-n-pasted to the text over links.  But pastebin links are better than screen shot images.  I saw your link but didn't check it, and didn't realize it included the traceback.)

Answer (score 1):

YOu know the problem, some images are being a pain, you'll have to debug I guess. Try to preform np.stack() everytime and catch where it goes wrong. The shape of all images will be printed when the stack no longer works, this might give you an idea what is going wrong. Can't help further since I can't reproduce it. np.stack concatenates all images on top of eachother, but therefore every image.shape has to be the same.

```
for image_name in train.Id:
    img_path = os.path.join(data_dir, 'train', img_name)
    img = imageio.imread(img_path)
    img = skimage.transform.resize(img, (32, 32), mode='constant')
    img = img.astype('float32') # this will help us in later stage
    temp.append(img)
    try:
        train_x = np.stack(temp)
    except ValueError:
        [print(im.shape) for im in temp]
        break
```

To give you a better feeling with np.stack, consider the following code:

```
tmp = [np.zeros((400,400,3)), np.zeros((400,400,3))]
print(np.stack(tmp).shape)
>>> (2, 400, 400, 3)

tmp = [np.zeros((400,400,3)), np.zeros((400,400))]
print(np.stack(tmp).shape)
>>> ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```

In the first example I have a list with two 3D arrays, with exactly the same shape. Numpy stacks them together and creates a new dimension, often called the batch size. In the second one I have a 3D and a 2D array in the list, and when you try to stack two arrays with a different shape (400, 400, 3) vs (400, 400) you get the ValueError you mentioned.

I also took the liberty to look at the skimage docs right [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread)
At the return you can see the following:

> img_array : ndarray
>   The different color bands/channels are stored in the third dimension, such that a gray-image is MxN, an RGB-image MxNx3 and an RGBA-image MxNx4.

I've the feeling some of your images are read as an MxNx4 array instead of MxNx3

Hope I helped a bit, feel free to ask me more.

EDIT

```
for image_name in train.Id:
    img_path = os.path.join(data_dir, 'train', img_name)
    img = imageio.imread(img_path)
    img = skimage.transform.resize(img, (32, 32), mode='constant')
    img = img.astype('float32') # this will help us in later stage
    if len(img.shape) == 3 and img.shape[-1] == 3  # only append if 3D and last dimension is a 3, standing for RGB
        temp.append(img)
train_x = np.stack(temp)
```

Comment: I couldn’t thank you enough.! You really put the whole issue into perspective. Anyhow, running the following code snippet indeed gave me an array of (32, 32) at the call for the break statement as you suggested it would. I guess one of the reasons I didn't understand what issue I was having was simply because I thought the third dimension was "3" by default when calling for the implementation Skimage. With the Skimage docs you provided, I was then able to go back and attribute the image name attached to that array shape just to confirm. And sure enough, I was pulling up a gray-image.

Comment: Can't do it now because class starts in a few and I'm sure it'll take more than a few minutes to process, but I'm hoping running it as  `img = skimage.transform.resize(img, (32, 32, 3), mode='constant')` will fix my issue. Once again, I'd like to thank you!

Comment: Apparently you can upscale a grayscale image to a 3D  image that way, not sure how trustworthy this upscaling is. It is generally better to know exactly how your data looks, and not to mix grayscales and RGB image. I'm gonna edit my code and provide a work around for you.